# Delphi: make ServiceDelete function

Tags: delphi, service

I would like to make a service delete function.

```
Function ServiceDelete(sMachine, sService: String): Boolean;
Var
  schm, schs: SC_Handle;
  ss: TServiceStatus;
  dwChkP: dword;
Begin
  Result := False;
  schm := OpenSCManager(PChar(sMachine), Nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  If schm > 0 Then Begin
    schs := OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), SERVICE_STOP Or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    If schs > 0 Then Begin
      If (QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss)) Then Begin
        While (SERVICE_STOPPED <> ss.dwCurrentState) Do Begin
          ControlService(schs, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, ss);
          dwChkP := ss.dwCheckPoint;
          Sleep(ss.dwWaitHint);
          If (Not QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss)) Then
            Break;
          If (ss.dwCheckPoint < dwChkP) Then
            Break;
        End;
      End;
      DeleteService(schs);
      CloseServiceHandle(schs);
    End;
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);

    // If service does not exist, then everything is fine.
    schm := OpenSCManager(PChar(sMachine), Nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
    If schm > 0 Then Begin
      schs := OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
      If schs = 0 Then Begin
        If GetLastError = ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST Then
          Result := True;
      End Else Begin
        CloseServiceHandle(schs);
      End;
      CloseServiceHandle(schm);
    End;
  End;
End;
```

It opens the the service manager, open the service, execute the DeleteService, but it does not delete the service. The function returns false, and the service still exists.
What do i do wrong?

Comment: You don't appear to check for errors consistently. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [DeleteService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682562(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Service Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx), you need to add `STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = $F0000;` to get

```
schs := OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED  or SERVICE_STOP Or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
```

Also, its important to run the program with administrator rights and to check each function result is OK as stated in the comments.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to comment from Remy Lebeau, its possible to narrow it further down to just require standard access right `Winapi.Windows._DELETE = $00010000;` to get

```
schs := OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), Winapi.Windows._DELETE or SERVICE_STOP Or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED was the solution. (I knew the admin rights rule.)

Comment: Perfect :)  I adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: @trob If you'd checked for errors, you'd have been told that access was denied. I can't understand why anyone would knowingly neglect error checking. The system will help you if you would only let it.

Comment: @ChristianHolmJørgensen: You don't need `STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED` to call `DeleteService()`, you only need `DELETE`. Both pages you link to in your answer say as much.  `STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED` includes `DELETE`, but also includes `READ_CONTROL`, `WRITE_DAC`, and `WRITE_OWNER`, which are not necessary or desired in this situation. `OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), _DELETE or SERVICE_STOP Or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, I adjusted the answer to include this input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks for You too, i changed it to _DELETE.